# XPath Замена результатов после поиска

Tags: xml, xpath

Ищу в XML-файле данные.
Например,использую выражение

```
"a:Баланс[@Валюта='Руб']/@Валюта"
```

Это дает мне массив строк "Руб".
Можно ли эти "Руб" в результатах заменить на любую другую строку, используя XPath 1.0?
Делать это после поиска в коде на ЯП не имею возможности. Нужно передать подготовленные данные. Автозамена в текстовом редакторе тоже не подходит.

Comment: Судя по всему вы пытаетесь сделать трансформацию. Для этого лучше использовать XSLT.

Comment: @РостиславКрасный нет, документ мне преобразовывать не нужно. Я читаю из него данные, используя шаблон, который тоже из себя представляет XML файл. В этом шаблоне есть теги XPath. Вместо "Руб" мне хотелось получить Id валюты в БД, чтобы в коде не преобразовывать. Но похоже выход один - думать над кодом.

Comment: XSL - это тоже XML файл с XPath внутри. Советую вам, всё же, рассмотреть возможность использовать XSLT, тем более вам всё равно придётся менять ваш код.